# How to list sub calls of conctract methods transferring money?

Tags: contract-invocation, web3.py

Assuming I have a contract method which conducts several money transfers, e.g.

```
function payalot(address payable p1, address payable p2, address payable p3) public {
    p1.transfer(42);
    p2.transfer(1337);
    p3.transfer(65535);
}
```

If I execute this method, I can easily get the executions' transaction hash and transaction receipt.

What I need to know is the list of money transfers conducted by the method. If I have the transaction hash or transaction receipt, is there any (easy) way of getting the details of "sub-calls" (is that the right name?) where money is transferred in Web3py - or in general?

Bonus question: Does that also work when tracking selfdestruct transactions?

Comment: You can emit an event for each transfer.

Comment: The contracts are given as input. I can't/I'm not allowed to change it. So I need a different approach.